# Correct way to enqueue js and css for external php scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am developing a plugin that uses some external PHP library. That PHP library uses js and CSS. I want to enqueue that external library js and CSS using the Wordpress enqueue functions in Wordpress admin area. I have tried using the add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'wp_db_fb_co_enqueue_scripts')); on the constructor function of the library but it doesn't work. I think I need to add some action hook as well.
Please let me know correct way to do this. Thanks

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'pdocrud_admin_enqueue_scripts'));        
}
public function pdocrud_admin_enqueue_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_script('wp-db-fb-co-frontend-script-js', WP_DB_FORM_BUILDER_CRUD_OPERATION_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/js/frontend-script.js');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but the problem might lie somewhere else. You need to make sure that the path to your JS file is correct and the function `pdocrud_admin_enqueue_scripts()` is being called correctly.

Also, make sure your constructor is being called in the context of a WordPress action that happens after plugins are loaded. Here's a simple example:

```
class MyPlugin {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
    }

    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin-script', plugins_url('/assets/js/frontend-script.js', __FILE__));
    }
}

// Hook into the 'plugins_loaded' action to create an instance of your plugin.
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
    new MyPlugin();
});
```

In this example, an instance of the **MyPlugin** class is created on the `plugins_loaded` action. This is a good place to initialize your plugin, as all the other plugins have been loaded by the time this action fires.

Also, note that in the `enqueue_scripts()` function, the `plugins_url()` function is being used to create the URL to the script file. This function generates the correct URL, regardless of where the plugin is installed. The `__FILE__` magic constant is being passed as the second argument to `plugins_url()` to specify that the path should be relative to the current file.

In your case, you'd replace `my-plugin-script` with `wp-db-fb-co-frontend-script-js`, and the URL to the script file with your URL.

And remember that `wp_enqueue_script()` function needs to be called before `wp_head()` function is executed. The admin_enqueue_scripts action is the appropriate hook to use for enqueuing scripts and styles in the admin area.

Answer (score -2):

The `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook is what you want, and then the `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions inside to actually register and enqueue the assets to be included.

Untested:

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', static function () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle', 'https://example.com/script.js', array(), '1.0.2' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-handle', 'https://example.com/style.css', array(), '1.0.2' );
} );
```

Comment: I have used the same add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'pdocrud_admin_enqueue_scripts')); but it's not calling. I have used same function in the plugin and it works perfectly there.

Comment: How/when is the class initialized?

Comment: The code suggested is just the same as what OP have already written.

Comment: @ray-happyforms The OP edited their question after receiving my answer.